# Calling methods for my java class

Tags: java, methods, call

I'm trying to create a method that asks the user for the number of names and values they want, then prompts the user to enter those names and values. Then it's suppose to return the first name of the person with the lowest value and print in main. Error keeps popping up that it cannot find the variable "name". Here's my code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String name = minValue();
    System.out.println(name);
}//end main

public static String minValue(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many first names are there?");
    int numOfNames = input.nextInt();
    for(int number = 0; number < numOfNames; number++){
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = input.next();
    }
    System.out.print("How many values are there?");
    int numOfValues = input.nextInt();
    for (int count = 0; count < numOfValues; count++){
        System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
        double value = input.nextDouble();
    }
    return name;
}//end minValue
```

I also believe I'm not doing something right with connecting the values to the name. Really confused with this.

Comment: Are you wanting to return all the names entered? At the moment you are asking for multiple names (and values) but only returning a single string.

Comment: You should add 2 ArrayList members to your class and add the names and values to these collections. Try that first, you'll see things make more sense then.

Comment: @Trengot I am just trying to get one name - the one with the lowest value

Comment: @helb we haven't covered arrays yet in my class. could you be more specific or is that too much to cover for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error keeps popping up that it cannot find the variable "name".

Move `name` out of the `for` loop:

```
String name = null;
for (int number = 0; number < numOfNames; number++) {
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name = input.next();
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `for` loop's braces (`{` and `}`) define a scope in which the variables are defined. Since you defined `name` inside that block, it will only be available inside it. By moving the declaration outside of the block to the scope of `return name`, it will be available for referencing.

> It's suppose to return the first name of the person with the lowest value and print in main.

If you want to remember the names and values you read you have to put them all in some data structure (an array, a list, a map etc.). I assume that you're trying to use the most basic structures, so work with arrays. Also, it makes no sense to have a different number of names and values in your case. Try to understand and complete this code:

```
public static String minValue() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many first names are there?");
    int numOfNames = input.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[numOfNames];
    double[] values = new double[numOfNames];
    for (int number = 0; number < numOfNames; number++) {
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        names[number] = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
        values[number] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    int i = 0;
    // write a way to get the index i of the smallest value in values

    return names[i];
}
```

Comment: really helpful input @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: @lobolb12 ChiefTwoPencils' comment seems irrelevant. Do you need any clarifications of have any questions about my answer?

Comment: @user1803551 no, everything is checking out good. not familiar with arrays but im reading up on them. i see where wasted my efforts and this helped a lot

Comment: Well, it was very helpful at the time when you provided an answer which had zero impact on the correct outcome for the problem. You, as everyone else jumping in for quick answers, neglected to realize that in addition to name being declared in a loop; *it was in a loop*. Your pre-edited answer suggested that all you had to do was move the declaration outside the loop while in fact it just created equally useless code. The simple comment above simply states that fact.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils You're confusing who wrote which comment. Besides, even in my first iteration of the question it answered 50% of the OP's question. You might also want to know that giving a quick answer and following up with edit expansions is the way most experienced users answer. I suggest that in the future you wait a bit before commenting on a fresh answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that misunderstanding. [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible#comment70084_267090) is what I've said in the past when it comes to fast answers. Experienced users, from what I've seen, are able to answer then clarify or expand. 50% is another way of saying half-assed. Regardless, IMHO, that you answered half the half you answered was useless in context of the obvious intent of the code and problem. I appreciate the advice but will continue to vote as fast as people are willing to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code instead! It helps you to store values in an array and write the code to minimum value in the space provided!

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many first names are there?");
        int numOfNames = input.nextInt();
        String name[]=new String[numOfNames];
        for (int number = 0; number < numOfNames; number++) {
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
             name[number] = input.next();
        }
        System.out.print("How many values are there?");
        int numOfValues = input.nextInt();
        double value[]=new double[numOfValues];
        for (int count = 0; count < numOfValues; count++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
            value[count] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        /* Write function to calculate min value here */
        return min value;
```

Comment: And how will it work if the number of values is greater than the number of names?

Comment: It depends on how he want to write the min value calculation function!

Answer (score 0):

In the method `minValue`, you defined the `String name` variable inside the first `for` loop, and then you are trying to access it outside the loop scope. You should do something like this:

```
public static String minValue(){

  ...
  String name = "";
  for( ... ) {
    name = input.next();
  }

  ...

  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `return name` at the end of your method but you don't declare it anywhere in the right scope. You've defined it within `main` (which means it is only available in that method) and in the for loop (which means it's re-created for each loop iteration and only available there).

You can add `String name = ""` at the start of your `minValue` method as a quick fix, but I suggest you read up on variable scope so you can learn why your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This should return name to you.
What you did is define name inside the for loop. this means as soon as a for loop run is done the name variable is discarded.
Define variables you wish to return or use outside of loops outside a loop(like at the beginning of the method.
This should work to return name to you.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String name = minValue();
  System.out.println(name);
}//end main

public static String minValue(){
  String name="none";
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("How many first names are there?");
  int numOfNames = input.nextInt();
for(int number = 0; number < numOfNames; number++){
  System.out.print("Enter name: ");
  name = input.next();
}
  System.out.print("How many values are there?");
  int numOfValues = input.nextInt();
for (int count = 0; count < numOfValues; count++){
   System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
   double value = input.nextDouble();
 }
 return name;
}//end minValue
```

Also this piece of code does entirely nothing with the double values...

```
  System.out.print("How many values are there?");
  int numOfValues = input.nextInt();
for (int count = 0; count < numOfValues; count++){
   System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
   double value = input.nextDouble();
 }
```

Comment: so what do I do then to make the values relevant to the names?

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to do, but now you are just getting a value and tossing it. Look at your assignment and go from there.